# keep track of a global value on a website

Tags: php, web

I'm currently working on a project that involves a website which gets data from a game API.

Problem is, I am bound to a specific Rate limit (of currently 500 requests per 10 minutes) which i must not exceed.

How do i keep track of the current count of requests other than writing / reading it to a file / database everytime someone requests the data (i guess that woulnd't be the best approach and could potentially ?! lead to problems with a few houndred people accessing the website at the same time)

The website calls a php script with neccessary information the user provides to get the data from the API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use APC for this.

> The Alternative PHP Cache (APC) is a free and open opcode cache for
>   PHP. Its goal is to provide a free, open, and robust framework for
>   caching and optimizing PHP intermediate code.

You don't need any external library to build this extension. Saving and fetching a variable across requests are as easy as this:

```
<?php
  $bar = 'BAR';
  apc_add('foo', $bar);
  var_dump(apc_fetch('foo'));

  echo "\n";

  $bar = 'NEVER GETS SET';
  apc_add('foo', $bar);
  var_dump(apc_fetch('foo'));
  echo "\n";
?>
```

[Here](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) is the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Since all requests are separate, they don't know anything about the other requests. There is no way to have a "shared" variable in PHP.

Best way is probably to create a database table and create a record in there every time you do a request. Keep track of when each request was made with a datetime column.
That way you can quickly check how many requests were done in the last 10minutes by counting the records made in the last 10 minutes.

Run a generic delete query on the table on occasion.

A simple query like that will not really hurt your performance unless you have a *really* busy site.

Another solution might be to cache the results from the API and re-use the results for each request. Then refresh the results from the API about every few seconds (1 request every 2 seconds ends up at 300/10minutes). But that would require the data to be actually cache-able and re-useable.